# Whats wrong with that RadCalendar Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

i'm trying to highlight comma seperated dates mentioned in textbox to radcalendar

```
Dim calendar As New RadCalendar()
calendar.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended
calendar.SelectedDates.Add(New DateTime(2008, 7, 7))
calendar.SelectedDates.Add(New DateTime(2008, 7, 8))
calendar.SelectedDates.Add(New DateTime(2008, 10, 10))
```

Code to Highlight textbox comma sepearted dates as 03-sep-2015, 04-sep-2015 on RadCalendar

```
Protected Sub RadCalendar1_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadCalendar1.PreRender
    Dim yourCalendar As RadCalendar
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        If [String].IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) = False Then
            'textbox in which dates as stored as comma separated
            Dim datesToShow As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(","c)
            For Each [date] As String In datesToShow
                yourCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(New DateTime([date]))
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Both of the code shows an error with bluecolor underline on both code as :

***Value of type 'Date' cannot be converted to 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadDate'.***

on yourCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(New DateTime([date]))

Line

Answer (score 0):

The RadCalendar.SelectedDates.Add method is expecting a attribute of the type "Telerik.Web.UI.RadDate" and you're passing in a DateTime type.

You should be newing up a [RadDate](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/api/server/Telerik.Web.UI/RadDate) instead of a DateTime.

Looks like RadDate has a Date property which is a DateTime.

So instead of

```
calendar.SelectedDates.Add(New DateTime(2008,7,7));
```

do

```
Dim d = New RadDate()
d.Date = New DateTime(2008, 7, 7)
calendar.SelectedDates.Add(d)
```

Comment: I'm new to RadControls can you guide me how do i modify that code to working one ?

Comment: It's not a RadControls issue really. It's a very basic .net error. I've stuck some VB in. I converted it from C#, doens't looks as clean as it would in C#. Someone who does VB might come and make it look better.

Comment: I made it make more sense, I think. :)

Comment: But i want to highlights dates dynamically in radcalendar which is entered in Textbox... any updated solution ?